# How to remove padding from a table cell?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with two columns. The left side us usually 1 word, and the second one with a bit more text. When I have too much text on the second column, the first one expands and center the text.

How do I remove this unwanted padding so the text will be on the top-left? 
[image]

Comment: Why are you showing us a picture of your HTML, instead of your HTML that we can copy/paste to create a demo?

Comment: I don't have permition to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add css in td or in .tlt `vertical-align:top`

Answer (score 1):

Inside a table-row, the two cells have always the same height. It shows as a padding, but it's automatically applied.

As some users mentioned, you can set a `vertical-align: top;` for the cell, and than play with padding top to position the text.

Answer (score 0):

in ALL browsers, the browser will make padding and margin between all the things. to remove that and control the page yourself add this add the first line of your css:

```
* {margin:0 auto; padding:0}
```

`auto` makes all the things (except text and images) at the center of your page.

and for your table if you want texts to be on top of your td, add this:

`.tlt{vartical-align:top; text-align:left;}`

Answer (score 0):

Just Select your Class via `.tlt` and add `vertical-align:top` you don't need to do anything more since for your `.tlt` just `padding-right` has been added so that there will be a space between two columns.

CSS

```
.tlt{
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Add it at the end of your Css Code.